# Why is the time taken different using async and await in a coroutine?

Tags: async-await, kotlin-coroutines

I have a question while learning coroutines.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        val time = measureTimeMillis {
            val a = async {
                delay(1000)
                "1"
            }
            val b = async {
                delay(1000)
                "2"
            }

            val a1 = a.await()
            val b1 = b.await()
        }

        println(time)
    }
}
```

Running this takes 1000

```kotlin
fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        val time = measureTimeMillis {
            val a = async {
                delay(1000)
                "1"
            }.await()
            val b = async {
                delay(1000)
                "2"
            }.await()
        }

        println(time)
    }
}
```

but Running this takes 2000

I'd like to know why this is happening
Does the behavior change depending on returning Deferred versus returning a value after execution?

Comment: In your second example, you wait for your first task before you even start the second task.

Comment: Why is there no wait in the first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`async`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/async.html) docs

> By default, the coroutine is immediately scheduled for execution.

In first case you simply launch two coroutines with `async`, which start executing immediately, by the time you call `await` on both of them they are up and running. so they both take only 1000 millis to complete.

but in second case you launch `a` and then wait for it to finish, this takes 1000 millis and then you start `b` and wait for it to finish, which also takes 1000 millis. so ultimatly this costs you 2000 millis.